# mongodb: Search a collection for all IDs in an array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search

I have an array of objects with only ObjectIDs and want to search a collection for all the documents with those IDs.

```js
var array = [{ _id: 5551e59be360594cd3319644 },
             { _id: 5551e59be360594cd3319631 },
             { _id: 5551e59be360594cd33195d2 },
             { _id: 5551e59be360594cd3319627 }];
```

Here is what I'm currently doing to get my result:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  db.collection('test').findOne({_id:array[i]._id}, function(err, matched) {
    console.log(matched);
});
```

I tried to work with the `$in`operator but had no success because it's not an array of IDs but an array of objects with those IDs inside.

Is there another way to do this with just one database query as I don't think it's a great idea to do so many database queries in a for loop.

**EDIT**
I now tried it with the map method (like @chrisdam explained) so I have an array of the IDs but when i pass it to the find method i get this result:

**EDIT2**
Nevermind my first edit. `find()` returns just a cursor, not the documents itself. So I used `toArray()`. Thanks for your help @chrisdam!!

```
{ db:
  { domain: null,
    _events: {},
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    databaseName: 'test',
    serverConfig: { 
      domain: null,
      _events: {},
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      auth: [Getter],
      _callBackStore: [Object],
      _commandsStore: [Object],
      _dbStore: [Object],
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 27017,
      options: [Object],
      internalMaster: true,
      connected: true,
      poolSize: 5,
      disableDriverBSONSizeCheck: false,
      _used: true,
      replicasetInstance: null,
      emitOpen: false,
      ssl: false,
      sslValidate: false,
      sslCA: null,
      sslCert: undefined,
      sslKey: undefined,
      sslPass: undefined,
      serverCapabilities: [Object],
      name: 'localhost:27017',
      socketOptions: [Object],
      logger: [Object],
      eventHandlers: [Object],
      _serverState: 'connected',
      _state: [Object],
      recordQueryStats: false,
      socketTimeoutMS: [Getter/Setter],
      _readPreference: [Object],
      db: [Circular],
      dbInstances: [Object],
      connectionPool: [Object],
      isMasterDoc: [Object] },
    options: { 
      read_preference_tags: null,
      read_preference: 'primary',
      url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
      native_parser: true,
      readPreference: [Object],
      safe: false,
      w: 1 },
    _applicationClosed: false,
    slaveOk: false,
    bufferMaxEntries: -1,
    native_parser: true,
    bsonLib: { 
      BSON: [Object],
      Long: [Object],
      ObjectID: [Object],
      DBRef: [Object],
      Code: [Object],
      Timestamp: [Object],
      Binary: [Object],
      Double: [Object],
      MaxKey: [Object],
      MinKey: [Object],
      Symbol: [Object] },
    bson: { promoteLongs: true },
    bson_deserializer: { 
      Code: [Object],
      Symbol: [Object],
      BSON: [Object],
      DBRef: [Object],
      Binary: [Object],
      ObjectID: [Object],
      Long: [Object],
      Timestamp: [Object],
      Double: [Object],
      MinKey: [Object],
      MaxKey: [Object],
      promoteLongs: true },
    bson_serializer: { 
      Code: [Object],
      Symbol: [Object],
      BSON: [Object],
      DBRef: [Object],
      Binary: [Object],
      ObjectID: [Object],
      Long: [Object],
      Timestamp: [Object],
      Double: [Object],
      MinKey: [Object],
      MaxKey: [Object],
      promoteLongs: true },
    _state: 'connected',
    pkFactory: { 
      [Function: ObjectID]
      index: 13651524,
      createPk: [Function: createPk],
      createFromTime: [Function: createFromTime],
      createFromHexString: [Function: createFromHexString],
      isValid: [Function: isValid],
      ObjectID: [Circular],
      ObjectId: [Circular] },
    forceServerObjectId: false,
    safe: false,
    notReplied: {},
    isInitializing: true,
    openCalled: true,
    commands: [],
    logger: { error: [Function], log: [Function], debug: [Function] },
    tag: 1431517732801,
    eventHandlers: { 
      error: [],
      parseError: [],
      poolReady: [],
      message: [],
      close: [] },
    serializeFunctions: false,
    raw: false,
    recordQueryStats: false,
    retryMiliSeconds: 1000,
    numberOfRetries: 60,
    readPreference: { _type: 'ReadPreference', mode: 'primary', tags: undefined } },
  collection: { 
    db: { 
      domain: null,
      _events: {},
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      databaseName: 'test',
      serverConfig: [Object],
      options: [Object],
      _applicationClosed: false,
      slaveOk: false,
      bufferMaxEntries: -1,
      native_parser: true,
      bsonLib: [Object],
      bson: [Object],
      bson_deserializer: [Object],
      bson_serializer: [Object],
      _state: 'connected',
      pkFactory: [Object],
      forceServerObjectId: false,
      safe: false,
      notReplied: {},
      isInitializing: true,
      openCalled: true,
      commands: [],
      logger: [Object],
      tag: 1431517732801,
      eventHandlers: [Object],
      serializeFunctions: false,
      raw: false,
      recordQueryStats: false,
      retryMiliSeconds: 1000,
      numberOfRetries: 60,
      readPreference: [Object] },
    collectionName: 'sick',
    internalHint: null,
    opts: {},
    slaveOk: false,
    serializeFunctions: false,
    raw: false,
    readPreference: { _type: 'ReadPreference', mode: 'primary', tags: undefined },
    pkFactory: { 
      [Function: ObjectID]
      index: 13651524,
      createPk: [Function: createPk],
      createFromTime: [Function: createFromTime],
      createFromHexString: [Function: createFromHexString],
      isValid: [Function: isValid],
      ObjectID: [Circular],
      ObjectId: [Circular] },
    serverCapabilities: undefined },
  selector: { _id: { '$in': [Object] } },
  fields: undefined,
  skipValue: 0,
  limitValue: 0,
  sortValue: undefined,
  hint: null,
  explainValue: undefined,
  snapshot: undefined,
  timeout: true,
  tailable: undefined,
  awaitdata: undefined,
  oplogReplay: undefined,
  numberOfRetries: 5,
  currentNumberOfRetries: 5,
  batchSizeValue: 0,
  raw: false,
  readPreference: { _type: 'ReadPreference', mode: 'primary', tags: undefined },
  returnKey: undefined,
  maxScan: undefined,
  min: undefined,
  max: undefined,
  showDiskLoc: undefined,
  comment: undefined,
  tailableRetryInterval: 100,
  exhaust: false,
  partial: false,
  slaveOk: false,
  maxTimeMSValue: undefined,
  connection: undefined,
  transforms: undefined,
  totalNumberOfRecords: 0,
  items: [],
  cursorId: { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: 0, high_: 0 },
  dbName: undefined,
  state: 0,
  queryRun: false,
  getMoreTimer: false,
  collectionName: 'test.sick' }
```

Comment: Why not loop over the list and create a new list with just the IDs, then use that with the `$in` operator.

Comment: @Sir_FZ We basically did that with the map function, didn't we?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the JavaScript's native **[map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method to generate an ObjectIds array that you can then use with the [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator as follows:

```
var array = [{ _id: "5551e59be360594cd3319644" },
             { _id: "5551e59be360594cd3319631" },
             { _id: "5551e59be360594cd33195d2" },
             { _id: "5551e59be360594cd3319627" }],    
    ids = array.map(function (obj){ return ObjectId(obj._id)});

db.collection.find({ "_id": { "$in": ids }});
```

OR just use the **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** operator as:

```
var array = [{ _id: "5551e59be360594cd3319644" },
             { _id: "5551e59be360594cd3319631" },
             { _id: "5551e59be360594cd33195d2" },
             { _id: "5551e59be360594cd3319627" }],    
    ids = array.map(function (obj){ return { _id: ObjectId(obj._id) } });   

db.collection.find({ "$or": ids });
```

Comment: Is there a way to get ids and then get corresponding objects for those ids in a single query(maybe with some form of aggregation)? Thanks